# How to check if the player has a role when the bot starts and sends the message "on_ready"

Tags: python, discord

Blockquote

I have a bug, I created a bot that issues a role when entering the members server, but sometimes the bot is offline and cannot issue a role
Therefore, I wanted the bot to display a role when the bot is started if the member does not have a role, and to do nothing if the member already has a role

I tried it but it doesn't work and yes I work because of the cog[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBsQU.png)

> 

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_ready(self, guild: discord.Guild):

    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=775777298111791104)

    for m in guild.members:
        for r in role.guild.members:
            if m.guild.roles != r.get_role(775777298111791104):
                print("Ok")
                await m.add_roles(role)
```

## =======================================================================

async def setup(bot):
await bot.add_cog(JoinMemberMessages(bot))

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you put the code that doesn't work in the question? We are unable to help if you don't provide us with what you've done/tried already.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75163920/edit) your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [full text of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), all as formatted text in the question itself. Do not post images of text. The code should be a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I edited and attached the code!

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a few fundamental issues with your code.

You're looping over the guild members and then for each guild member you're starting another loop where you're looping over the guild members again? Then you're checking if **all** the server's role is equal to one particular role?
Additionally, the `on_ready` event doesn't take `guild` as a parameter

Your code doesn't quite do what you suggest it's trying to do.

```py
async def on_ready(self):

    # if your client/bot is instantiated as another var - then change this
    # perhaps if it's `client` or `self.bot` or whatever
    guild = await bot.fetch_guild(YOUR_GUILD_ID)
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=MY_ROLE_ID)

    for member in guild.members:
        member_roles = member.roles
        member_role_ids = [role.id for role in member_roles]
        if MY_ROLE_ID in member_roles_ids:
            # user already has our role
            continue
        await member.add_roles(role)
        print(f"Given {member.name} the {role.name} role")
```

Replace CAPITAL_VARIABLES with yours or the relevant magic numbers.

Here, we loop over the members and check they don't have the existing role ID; and assign it to them if they don't.

Perhaps check the docs:

- [`on_ready`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_ready)
- [`discord.Guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#guild)
- [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member)